# Listing background broken by \colorbox and \framebox

Tags: listings, boxes, backgrounds

I am using `listing` environment (`listings` package) with the background parameter. I want to highlight some lines of code and I am using the `\colorbox`, `\makebox` and `\framebox` to achieve this. However, a problem with my solution is that the background is broken (space without background in the `listing` environment).

Would you please to help me to solve out this problem.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Montpellier}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Background broken}
\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=$, backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray}]
int a = 0;
$\colorbox{green}{int b = 0;}$
int c = 0;
$\framebox{int d = 0;}$
int e = 0;
int f = 0;
int g = 0;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the very powerful `tcolorbox` package, so the background is colored on a global basis, rather than line by line:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Montpellier}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\newcommand{\lcolorbox}[2]{%
  \hspace*{-\fboxsep}\colorbox{#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\lfbox}[1]{%
  \hspace*{-\fboxsep}\hspace*{-\fboxrule}\fbox{#1}%
}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Background broken}
\lstset{escapechar=$}
\begin{tcblisting}{
  listing only,
  colback=lightgray,
}
int a = 0;
$\lcolorbox{green}{int b = 0;}$
int c = 0;
$\lfbox{int d = 0;}$
int e = 0;
int f = 0;
int g = 0;
\end{tcblisting}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I have also provided some commands for adjusting the horizontal position of the boxes.

[image]

Comment: You get a gray line between consecutive lines if you highlight them. That might not be the desired result.

Comment: @maiermic I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Replace `int c = 0;` with `$\lcolorbox{green}{int c = 0;}$` and you get a gray line between the two green boxes.

Comment: @maiermic And what's the problem? If you need no separation between highlighted lines, that's the object of a new question.

Comment: That's what I did: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/496920/71644

Answer (score 6):

If you want to highlight entire lines, you can exploit the features of the [`lstlinebgrd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lstaddons) package.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Montpellier}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstlinebgrd}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Background broken}
\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=$,linebackgroundcolor={\ifnum\value{lstnumber}=2\color{green}\else\color{lightgray}\fi}]
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;
int d = 0;
int e = 0;
int f = 0;
int g = 0;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can set `\fboxsep` to  a suitable value. `\fboxsep=1.5pt` seems to work fine.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Montpellier}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\fboxsep=1.5pt                     %% adjust
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Background broken}
\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=$, backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray}]
int a = 0;
$\colorbox{green}{int b = 0;}$
int c = 0;
$\framebox{int d = 0;}$
int e = 0;
int f = 0;
int g = 0;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Montpellier}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\fboxsep=1.5pt                     %% adjust
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Background broken}
\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=$, backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily]
int a = 0;
$\colorbox{green}{int b = 0;}$
int c = 0;
$\framebox{int g = 0;}$
int e = 0;
int f = 0;
int g = 0;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this does not work if we use the ttfamily font (basicstyle={\footnotesize\ttfamily})

Comment: @AnCongTran Is it? See the edit.

Comment: If you replace "int d = 0;" by "int g = 0;" you will see the problem.

Comment: @AnCongTran Sorry, but what is the problem?

Comment: It is so weird. If I replace "int d = 0;" by "int g = 0;", a gap appears between "int g" and "int d" (as in my question). I do not know how to attach the figure in this section.