# acmart: problem with listings line height

Tags: listings, line-spacing, acm

I'm using [`acmart`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/acmart?lang=en) with `listings` and having a problem with line height. If I set `backgroundcolor`, the shaded height of the line doesn't match the actual height:

[image]

```
\documentclass{acmart}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}


\definecolor{verylightgray}{gray}{0.9}
\lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{verylightgray}}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
obj merchant {
   customer.payMethod
   customer.bankTransfer
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

If I replace `acmart` by `article` the problem mostly goes away:

[image]

although interestingly there does seem to be a faintly visible white line, even with `article`.

Comment: It's a common problem; I addressed it with `tcolorbox` in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159569/listing-background-broken-by-colorbox-and-framebox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tcolorbox`, which draws a solid background:

```
\documentclass{acmart}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{verylightgray}{gray}{0.9}

\newtcblisting{graylstlisting}[1][]
 {
  spartan,
  frame empty,
  boxsep=0mm,
  left=1mm,right=1mm,top=1mm,bottom=1mm,
  listing only,
  colback=verylightgray,
  listing options={
    basicstyle=\normalfont,
    #1
  },
 }


\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{graylstlisting}
obj merchant {
   customer.payMethod
   customer.bankTransfer
}
\end{graylstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can add `listings` options as optional argument to `graylstlisting` or define a style and apply it.