# Extra blank line above and below code listing

Tags: spacing, listings, tcolorbox

I'm trying to use @egreg's answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/362093) about obtaining a uniform background colour with the `listings` package. In my MSE I'm using the [acmart](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/acmart?lang=en) class to reproduce the problem from the original question (and thus motivate my use of `tcolorbox` in the first place), but the problem also arises with `article`.

The problem is that using `tcolorbox` to provide a listings environment produces an additional blank line of "padding" above and below the listed code, as shown in the second listing below:

[image]

There are two other problems with the `tcolorbox` solution: the placement of the line numbers differs from the plain `lstlistings` version, and the width of the shaded region doesn't quite run to the edge of the column. (The latter is not hugely problematic.)

```
\documentclass{acmart}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\definecolor{verylightgray}{gray}{0.9}

\newtcblisting{graylstlisting}[1][]
{
  spartan,
  frame empty,
  boxsep=0mm,
  listing only,
  colback=verylightgray,
  listing options={
    #1
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[
  numbers=left,
  backgroundcolor=\color{verylightgray}
]
f g h
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{graylstlisting}[
  numbers=left,
  backgroundcolor=\color{verylightgray}
]
f g h
\end{graylstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to use the `tcolorbox` solution for listings backgrounds, without introducing these other differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\definecolor{verylightgray}{gray}{0.9}

\newtcblisting{graylstlisting}[1][]
{
  spartan,
  frame empty,
  boxsep=0mm,
  listing only,
  colback=verylightgray,
  top = 0pt, %<-
  bottom = 0pt,%<- 
  left=0pt,%<- 
  listing options={
   numbersep=10pt,% <-
   xleftmargin=0pt,%<-
   aboveskip = 0pt,%<-
   belowskip = 0pt,%<-
    #1
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[
  numbers=left,
  backgroundcolor=\color{verylightgray}
]
f g h
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{graylstlisting}[
  numbers=left,
  backgroundcolor=\color{verylightgray}
]
f g h
\end{graylstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That does it for me. Thanks!