# Highlighting code snippet in lstlisting with colorbox changes the character and breaks the border

Tags: listings, colorbox

I am using Texstudio with texlive 2021. To highlight some lines of the following code snippet in `lstlisting`, I am using `colorbox`

```
        \begin{lstlisting}[style=listing1]
        |\colorbox{yellow}{if(a >= b)}| 
           return 2*a;
        return 2*b;
        \end{lstlisting}
```

Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstdefinestyle{listing1}{
    tabsize=1, 
    frame=single, 
    framerule=2pt, 
    frameround=tttt,       
    breakatwhitespace=false,          
    breaklines=true,                 
    deletekeywords={...},            
    escapeinside={\%*}{*)},           
    keepspaces=true,                 
    morekeywords={*,...},      
    numbers=left,                  
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray}, 
    rulecolor=\color{black},         
    showspaces=false,               
    showstringspaces=false,          
    showtabs=false,                  
    stepnumber=1,                    
    title=\lstname,
    linewidth=3.8cm, 
    xleftmargin=0.2cm, 
    escapechar=|, 
}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{lstlisting}[style=listing1]
    |\colorbox{yellow}{if(a >= b)}| 
       return 2*a;
    return 2*b;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

There are two issues: the border is broken,  and the character `>` has changed to `?`. Any idea?

[image]

Please don't suggest using `lstlinebgrd` as it raises the error in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451532/recent-issues-with-lstlinebgrd-package-with-listings-after-the-latters-updates) in TexLive 2021 and no fix yet. Also the solution in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159569/listing-background-broken-by-colorbox-and-framebox) didn't work for me.

Comment: you should make a small but complete example. That makes it much easier to test your issue.

Comment: Added the complete example.

Answer (score 1):

You get rid of the wrong symbols by using T1-encoding.

You avoid the gaps in the border either by making the colorbox smaller (by changing \fboxsep), or by enlarging the distances of the lines.
A better solution is to use tcolorbox for the frame.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstdefinestyle{listing1}{
    tabsize=1,
    frame=single,
    framerule=2pt,
    frameround=tttt,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    deletekeywords={...},
    escapeinside={\%*}{*)},
    keepspaces=true,
    morekeywords={*,...},
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    rulecolor=\color{black},
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    stepnumber=1,
    title=\lstname,
    linewidth=3.8cm,
    xleftmargin=0.2cm,
    escapechar=|,
}

%\AddToHook{env/lstlisting/begin}{\fboxsep=0pt} %smaller colorbox
\AddToHook{env/lstlisting/begin}{\fontsize{11pt}{19pt}\selectfont} %larger line distance
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=listing1]
    |\colorbox{yellow}{if(a >= b)}|
       return 2*a;
    return 2*b;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Including`\usepackage{tcolorbox}` gives the followings error: 
`(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.908 ...eoperator{||}{or}        {2}{infix} {200}`

Comment: T1-encoding fixed the problem with the wrong symbol. But broken frame is still there. Since I have to use springer Nature journal *cls I cannot use tcolorbox. 
The do class is https://gist.github.com/sepideha/1e59f68dd24bd9f973ae9bcf49ce04ee

Answer (score 0):

I know it not what You want to see but I am no very good at listing and hope MWE will help You to achive result what You need.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
language=C,                 
morekeywords={*,...},      
numbers=left,                  
numbersep=10pt,              
numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray}, 
rulecolor=\color{black},         
showspaces=false,               
showstringspaces=false,          
showtabs=false,                  
stepnumber=1,                    
stringstyle=\color{mymauve},     
title=\lstname,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        showstringspaces=false,
        breaklines=true,
        keywordstyle={},
        frame=none,%              changed to "none"
        rulecolor=\color{gray},
        escapechar=|
}


\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt,leftmargin=1cm,rightmargin=5cm,%
innerleftmargin=1cm,innerrightmargin=1cm]
\begin{lstlisting}
|\colorbox{green}{if(a >= b)}| 
  return 2*a;
    return 2*b;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{mdframed}
        

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, though it compiles to an empty box and texts outside in my with pdflatex in texstudio.